# how to create automatic snapshots for oracle virtual box?

Tags: virtualbox

Is it possible to write a script that takes automated snapshots of Oracle Virtual Box without shutting the VM.

The host operating system is Windows 7.

Answer (score 3):

Try "VBoxManage.exe snapshot MyVM take MySnapshot".

Comment: I ran this from windows command prompt and I got an error. It goes like: " A critical error has occurred while running the virtual machine and the machine execution has been stopped.

Comment: @Sandeep, It appears you need to pause the VM first: "VBoxManage snapshot VM_NAME take SNAPSHOT_NAME --pause" as a workaround to a [known bug](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/9255).

Answer (score 1):

I created a simple script to automatically snapshot my virtual machines.

GitHub: https://github.com/Meru3m/virtualbox-snapshotter

Comment: I think it's a bit overkill to have 22 dependencies to make virtualbox snapshots but it looks like an interesting tool

Comment: Yeah, you're right, but at the moment I didn't find a better way.
Maybe in future I'll be able to reduce the amount of dependencies :)